# How to escape one doulbe quote " in data file for psql \COPY import?

Tags: postgresql, psql

There are many standalone double quote '"' in a tab delimited text file, need to be loaded into PostgreSQL with psql \copy command.

If I use `FORMAT CSV` option, I have to specify the QUOTE, and QUOTE char needs to be paired.

Here is the code, and output,

```
create table t1(
  c1 varchar(20),
  n1 numeric
);

echo 'Alf_7"    5.12' > m.csv

psql> \copy t1 FROM 'm.csv' (FORMAT CSV, delimiter E'\t', NULL 'NULL', HEADER false);
ERROR:  unterminated CSV quoted field
CONTEXT:  COPY t1, line 1: "Alfa_7" 5.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `FORMAT text` option. then you do not have to specify the QUOTE.

```
psql=> \copy t1 FROM 'm.csv' (FORMAT text, delimiter E'\t', NULL 'NULL', HEADER false);

COPY 1
```

Comment: But then the backslashes have to be quoted. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: @DanielVérité ,  Can you give me an example?

Comment: Example: if a field is `c:\name` it will be imported as `c:` followed by a newline followed by `ame` because `\n` represents a newline in the text format. The field must contain `c:\\name` to be imported as `c:\name`, which means quoting the backslashes.

Comment: Cool, thanks @DanielVérité .  So many conner cases.  Is there a good way to deal with it ?

Comment: By adding a backslash before every backslash. Can be done with COPY's program clause: `\copy tablename from program 'cat myfile.txt | sed -e ''s/\\/\\\\/'''`.

Comment: @DanielVérité Cool, thanks. I'll remember this workaround.   ^_^ .  Hope \copy can do some preprocess like Oracle SQL*Loader in future.